# How to navigate to a url with different 'id' property using axios library in redux

Tags: redux, axios

I am working on a redux project where I have a list of posts(like Blog Post) and each post has an unique id.Also,I have a different component which displays the detail of a particular post(I have named it Post_Detail component). So what I want to do is when I click on a particular post from the list of posts,I want to navigate to the page which displays the detail of that particular post.

My **action creator** for displaying a selected post is:

```
//Action Creator for displaying a selected post
export function fetchPost(id) {
    const request = axios.get(`${API}/posts/${id}`,{headers});

    return dispatch => {
      return request.then(({data}) => {
        console.log(data);
        dispatch({
        type: FETCH_POST,
        payload: data
        })
      })
    }
}
```

My Post_Detail component for displaying the selected post is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPost, deletePost } from '../actions/posts_action';

class PostDetail extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const  { id } = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.fetchPost(id);
        console.log(id)
    }

    //Function for deleting on click using action creator
    onDeleteClick() {
      const { id } = this.props.match.params;
      this.props.deletePost(id, () => {
        this.props.history.push('/');
      });
    }

    render() {
      const { post } = this.props;

      if (!post) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
      }

      return(
        <div>
          <div>
            <h3>{post.title}</h3>
            <h6>Categories: {post.category}</h6>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
          </div>
          <button
            className="btn btn-danger pull-xs-right"
            onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this)} >
            Delete Post
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ posts }, ownProps) {
    return { post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPost, deletePost })(PostDetail);
```

My homepage for listing all the available posts is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reducers from './reducers/index.js'
import Posts from './components/posts_index';
import CreatePost from './components/new_post';
import PostDetail from './components/post_detail';
import CategoryView from './components/category';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

//const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(reducers,applyMiddleware(thunk));

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
 const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route  path="/new" component={CreatePost} />
          <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostDetail} />
          <Route exact  path="/" component={Posts} />
          <Route path="/:category/posts" component={CategoryView} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

So, what is happening now is if I try to navigate to the post using the "id" for that post in the url like : **http://localhost:3000/posts/8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd**  where "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd" is the id of that post,I can navigate to the Post_Detail component and see the details of that post.But,I am not able to figure out how to navigate to the Post_Detail component when the post is clicked from the list of posts in the homepage. I know that I should use a **"Link"** from 'react-router-dom' and navigate to the page passing in the url in **"to"** property of the link, but I don't know how to dynamically change the id in the link. Can anyone please guide me how to proceed?

Comment: Are you fetching your posts from an API?